# Обработка события для нескольких модальных окон js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть несколько модальных окон:

[Пример с моими тщетными попытками](http://embed.plnkr.co/uaIbfCiWo5wCkSnkrpgl/)

При раскрытии модального окна есть копка при клике на которую, окно должно закрываться, проблема в том, **что кнопка отрабатывает только на последнем окне**
Как правильно пройтись по элементам, чтобы эта копка и последующие элементы, например (window.onclick) отрабатывались на всех окнах?

Comment: "id = messageDialogBtnClose" - id должно быть уникальным.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас на странице не должно быть элементов с одинаковым id. Ваш код не стал разбирать, набросал свой вариант, можно сделать так.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  // Вешаем событие при нажатии на Show
  var Show = document.getElementsByClassName('button-light');
  [].forEach.call(Show, function(element, i) {       
    element.addEventListener('click', function(){
      showMessageDialog(i);
    });
  });

  // Вешаем событие при нажатии на Ok
  var Close = document.getElementsByClassName('button-primary');
  [].forEach.call(Close, function(element, i) {       
    element.addEventListener('click', function(){
      closeMessageDialog(i);
    });
  });

});

function showMessageDialog(i){
  var modal = document.getElementsByClassName('ui-message-box__wrapper')[i];   
  modal.style.display = "block";   
}

function closeMessageDialog(i){
  var modal = document.getElementsByClassName('ui-message-box__wrapper')[i];   
  modal.style.display = "none";   
}
```

```css
.ui-message-box__wrapper {
 display: none;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 z-index: 2002;
 background-color: rgba(39,39,39,0.48);
}

.ui-message-box {
 display: block;
 position: fixed;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 min-width: 400px;
 transform: translateX(-50%);
 padding: 12px 14px;
 background-color: #edf2fc;
 border: 1px solid #ebeef5;
 border-radius: 8px;
 z-index: 2000;
 animation: fadeInDown 0.3s;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.ui-message-box .button-close {
 width: 22px;
 height: 22px;
}

.ui-message-box__header {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: space-between;
 padding-bottom: 8px;
 margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.ui-message-box__content {
 margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.ui-message-box__footer {
 text-align: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.message-box-title {
 font-size: rem(24);
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeInDown {
 from {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
 }

 to {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInDown {
 from {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
 }

 to {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 }
}

@-o-keyframes fadeInDown {
 from {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
 }

 to {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 }
}

@keyframes fadeInDown {
 from {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
 }

 to {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 }
}
```

```html
<section class="message-box-doc">
    <div class="container"><span class="ui-title-2">Standart Message-box:</span>
      <div class="example-empty">
        <div class="ui-message-box__wrapper" id="exampleModal">
          <div class="ui-message-box">
            <div class="ui-message-box__header"><span class="message-box-title">Title</span><span class="button-close" ></span></div>
            <div class="ui-message-box__content"><span>Message is here</span></div>
            <div class="ui-message-box__footer">
              <div class="button button-primary">OK</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="button button-light">Show</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="message-box-doc">
    <div class="container"><span class="ui-title-2">Standart Message-box:</span>
      <div class="example-empty">
        <div class="ui-message-box__wrapper" id="exampleModal2">
          <div class="ui-message-box">
            <div class="ui-message-box__header"><span class="message-box-title">Title2</span><span class="button-close" ></span></div>
            <div class="ui-message-box__content"><span>Message is here2</span></div>
            <div class="ui-message-box__footer">
              <div class="button button-primary">OK</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="button button-light">Show</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```